# Pupeteer: send array of elementHandle to page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, browser, puppeteer

In Pupeteer, I'd like to pass an arbitrary number of [ElementHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.1.0/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) to the method evaluate in an array:

```
const element1=await page.$(".element")
const element2=await page.$(".another-element")

await page.evaluate((elements)=>{
  // do stuff with the array of elements
,[element1, element2]);
```

But, because ElementHandle is not serializable, the following error appears:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: See also [Puppeteer: Converting circular structure to JSON Are you passing a nested JSHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58870660/puppeteer-converting-circular-structure-to-json-are-you-passing-a-nested-jshand/68294113#68294113)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. But you can simply convert your array of elemetHandles with help of spread to arguments and then use rest operator to gather them again to the array:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="element">element 1</div>
        <div class="element">element 2</div>
        <div class="element">element 3</div>
    </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const element1 = await page.$('.element:nth-child(1)');
    const element2 = await page.$('.element:nth-child(2)');
    const element3 = await page.$('.element:nth-child(3)');

    const result = await page.evaluate((...elements) => {
        // do stuff with the array of elements
        return elements.map(element => element.textContent);
    }, ...[element1, element2, element3]);

    console.log(result);
    await browser.close();
})();
```