# Puppeteer: Converting circular structure to JSON Are you passing a nested JSHandle?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a one-page website. There are multiple selection combinations that would result in different search redirects. I wrote a for loop in the `page.evaluate`'s call back function to click the different selections and did the click search in every button. However, I got error: Converting circular structure to JSON Are you passing a nested JSHandle?

Please help!

My current version of code looks like this:

```js
const res = await page.evaluate(async (i, courseCountArr, page) => {
    for (let j = 1; j < courseCountArr[i]; j++) {
        await document.querySelectorAll('.btn-group > button, .bootstrap-select > button')['1'].click() // click on school drop down
        await document.querySelectorAll('div.bs-container > div.dropdown-menu > ul > li > a')[`${j}`].click() // click on each school option
        await document.querySelectorAll('.btn-group > button, .bootstrap-select > button')['2'].click() // click on subject drop down
        const subjectLen = document.querySelectorAll('div.bs-container > div.dropdown-menu > ul > li > a').length // length of the subject drop down
        for (let k = 1; k < subjectLen; k++) {
            await document.querySelectorAll('div.bs-container > div.dropdown-menu > ul > li > a')[`${k}`].click() // click on each subject option
            document.getElementById('buttonSearch').click() //click on search button
            page.waitForSelector('.strong, .section-body')
            return document.querySelectorAll('.strong, .section-body').length
        }
    }
}, i, courseCountArr, page);
```

Comment: The first thing to work on would be removing the `page.waitForSelector('.strong, .section-body')`, you can't do that inside the evaluate.

Comment: How do I wait the for the page to load after the search button is clicked and page is redirected?

Comment: You will need to split that in many evaluate calls.

Answer (score 12):

#### Why the error happens

While you haven't shown enough code to reproduce the problem (is `courseCountArr` an array of ElementHandles? Passing `page` to `evaluate` won't work either, that's a Node object), here's a minimal reproduction that shows the likely pattern:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  const html = `<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul>`;
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);

// ...
  const nestedHandle = await page.$$("li"); // $$ selects all matches
  await page.evaluate(els => {}, nestedHandle); // throws
// ...

})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

The output is

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'BrowserContext'
    |     property '_browser' -> object with constructor 'Browser'
    --- property '_defaultContext' closes the circle Are you passing a nested JSHandle?
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Why is this happening? All code inside of the callback to [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate) (and family: [`evaluateHandle`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluatehandle), [`$eval`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page._eval), [`$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.__eval)) is executed inside the browser console programmatically by Puppeteer. The browser console is a distinct environment from Node, where Puppeteer and the ElementHandles live. To bridge the inter-process gap, the callback to `evaluate`, parameters and return value are serialized and deserialized.

The consequence of this is that you can't access any Node state like you're attempting with `page.waitForSelector('.strong, .section-body')` inside the browser. `page` is in a totally different process from the browser. (As an aside, [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is purely synchronous, so there's no point in `await`ing it.)

Puppeteer [ElementHandles](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.elementhandle) are complex structures used to hook into the page's DOM that can't be serialized and passed to the page as you're trying to do. Puppeteer has to perform the translation under the hood. Any ElementHandles passed to `evaluate` (or have `.evaluate()` called on them) are followed to the DOM node in the browser that they represent, and that DOM node is what your `evaluate`'s callback is invoked with. Puppeteer can't do this with nested ElementHandles, as of the time of writing.

#### Possible fixes

In the above code, if you change [`.$$`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) to [`.$`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector), you'll retrieve only the first `<li>`. This singular, non-nested ElementHandle can be converted to an element:

```js
// ...
  const handle = await page.$("li");
  const val = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, handle);
  console.log(val); // => a
// ...
```

Or:

```js
const handle = await page.$("li");
const val = await handle.evaluate(el => el.innerText);
console.log(val); // => a
```

Making this work on your example is a matter of either swapping the loop and the `evaluate` call so that you access `courseCountArr[i]` in Puppeteer land, unpacking the nested ElementHandles into separate parameters to `evaluate`, *or* moving most of your console browser calls to click on things back to Puppeteer (depending on your use case and goals with the code).

You could apply the `evaluate` call to each ElementHandle:

```js
const nestedHandles = await page.$$("li");

for (const handle of nestedHandles) {
  const val = await handle.evaluate(el => el.innerText);
  console.log(val); // a b c
}
```

To get an array of results, you could do:

```js
const nestedHandles = await page.$$("li");
const vals = await Promise.all(
  nestedHandles.map(el => el.evaluate(el => el.innerText))
);
console.log(vals); // [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

You can also unpack the ElementHandles into arguments for `evaluate` and use the `(...els)` parameter list in the callback:

```js
const nestedHandles = await page.$$("li");
const vals = await page.evaluate((...els) =>
  els.map(e => e.innerText),
  ...nestedHandles
);
console.log(vals); // => [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

If you have other arguments in addition to the handles you can do:

```js
const nestedHandle = await page.$$("li");
const vals = await page.evaluate((foo, bar, ...els) => 
  els.map(e => e.innerText + foo + bar)
, 1, 2, ...nestedHandle);
console.log(vals); // => [ 'a12', 'b12', 'c12' ]
```

or:

```js
const nestedHandle = await page.$$("li");
const vals = await page.evaluate(({foo, bar}, ...els) => 
  els.map(e => e.innerText + foo + bar)
, {foo: 1, bar: 2}, ...nestedHandle);
console.log(vals); // => [ 'a12', 'b12', 'c12' ]
```

Another option may be to use `$$eval`, which selects multiple handles, then runs a callback in browser context with the array of selected elements as its parameter:

```js
const vals = await page.$$eval("li", els => 
  els.map(e => e.innerText)
);
console.log(vals); // => [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

This is probably cleanest if you're not doing anything else with the handles in Node.

Similarly, you can totally bypass Puppeteer and do the entire selection and manipulation in browser context:

```js
const vals = await page.evaluate(() =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll("li")].map(e => e.innerText)
);
console.log(vals); // => [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

*(note that getting the inner text throughout is just a placeholder for whatever browser code of arbitrary complexity you might have)*

Comment: You're the MVP !! Have been trying to solve this for ages !

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little utility to solve this problem

```
const jsHandleToJSON = (jsHandle) => {
  if (jsHandle.length > 0) {
    let json = []
    for (let i = 0; i < jsHandle.length; i++) {
      json.push(jsHandleToJSON(jsHandle[i]))
    }
    return json
  } else {
    let json = {}
    const keys = Object.keys(jsHandle)
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (typeof jsHandle[keys[i]] !== 'object') {
        json[keys[i]] = jsHandle[keys[i]]
      } else if (['elements', 'element'].includes(keys[i])) {
        json[keys[i]] = jsHandleToJSON(jsHandle[keys[i]])
      } else {
        console.log(`skipping field ${keys[i]}`)
      }
    }
    return json
  }
}
```

It will create a new object with all the primitive fields of the jsHandle (recursively) and parse some extra jsHandle properties `['elements', 'element']`, skips the others.
You could add more properties in there if you need them (but adding all of them will result in a infinite loop).

To make the log into puppeteer working you need to add the following line before the `evaluate`

```
page.on('console', message => console.log(`${message.type()}: ${message.text()}`))
```